# Apply const_cast to a string literal?

Tags: c++, string, constants

I need some predefined constant c-style string literals in my c++ code.

Can I use `const_cast<char *>` directly on a string literal?

I.E., is this legal (and is it a good idea) for a routine expecting a read-only `char*` argument?

```
const_cast<char*>("PIOFLAG")
```

Or should I just use `char *pf="PIOFLAG"` and use `pf` as an argument?

Comment: Is it your intention to modify these strings? If so, you can't rely on a literal to be writeable.

Comment: No, I don't need to modify it, just read. But the API has `char*` rather than `const char*`

Comment: Can't you use built in arrays? `char pf[] = "PIOFLAG";`.

Comment: @mfontanini: That is not really helping matters if the string isn't being modified, but takes up more space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string is used in an API that takes `char *` but in fact isn't modifying the string itself, then `const_cast<char *>("SOME STRING")` will be fine. Ideally, you'd modify the API to have a `const` parameter instead, which would make it much easier to use, and reflect reality.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe: So submit a bug report. Are you *certain* that it won't try to modify the string?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You just create another `char *` with its own memory allocation and copy the string in to it.

Casting away the constness of an inherently `const` object and modifying it eventually gives you Undefined Behavior so it is not really a good idea. Even if you don't plan to modify the object its still not a good idea because you defeat the entire purpose of const correctness and expose your code to whims and fancies of others as well as yourselves.

```
char *pf="PIOFLAG";
```

This usage is deprecated in C++, You must use a `const char *` while declaring a string literal.

Comment: This is too complicated to use: to decide how to delete the allocated memory, you have to understand how the API uses it (which might be tricky and implementation-dependent). If you do casting, it's enough to know that the API doesn't change it.

Comment: @anatolyg: Simple answer to your objection: It depends. There is not enough information in the OP for us to decide.

Answer (score 0):

you can const_cast the string literal that way, but not need it really, as there is an implicit conversion to char* (that is depreceted).

However you're not allowed to modify the string through that pointer.